# Script write to file permission denied

Tags: bash, scripting, ubuntu-18.04

I really did try to find the answer before asking. Sorry if this is a duplicate. This is a homework assignment. I need to create a script that pulls username and finds specific info (username, home directory, shell) in /etc/password to display and write to some file. The home directory contents should also be displayed and written to this same file.

sudo works, but I don't want it to require sudo to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script will display your username, grab your shell and home directory, provide a list of what is in your home directory, and write this information to a file."

# assign the values to variables
usrEntry=$(grep $USER /etc/passwd)
usrName=$(echo $usrEntry|cut -f1 -d:)
usrHome=$(echo $usrEntry|cut -f6 -d:)
usrShell=$(echo $usrEntry|cut -f7 -d:|cut -f3 -d/))
usrHomeSize=$(ls $usrHome -lh|head -1)
usrHomeList=$(ls $usrHome -lh|tail --lines=+2)
outputFile="$usrHome/UserInfo.txt"

# display username, home directory, and shell
echo "Your username is $usrName"
echo "Your home directory is $usrHome"
echo "You are using the $usrShell shell"

# display contents of home directory
echo "Your home directory contents:"
ls $usrHome -lh

# write results to file, formatted
echo "The script will now append this information to the UserInfo.txt file. If this file does not exist, a new one will be created."
echo "-----New Run-----" >> $outputFile
printf "%s: %s\n" "Username" $usrName "Home Directory" $usrHome "UserShell" $usrShell >> $outputFile
echo "Home Contents" >> $outputFile
printf "%s %s\n" $usrHomeSize >> $outputFile
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" $usrHomeList >> $outputFile
echo "Thank you for using my script. Maybe someday someone will find this useful"
exit 0
```

If what this is trying to accomplish is not clear, I can explain more, but I think I've covered it. I get multiple lines of permission denied.

```
/usr/local/bin/UserInfo.sh: line xx: /UserInfo.txt: Permission denied
```

where xx is lines 25 through 29. These are all the

```
printf/echo "some text" >> $outputFile
```

---

Edit: I've since come to find out that I cannot, in fact, write or touch anything in my own home directory, so I have to fix that and double check this script once done.

Edit 2: My home folder was owned by root. fixed that, still cannot write to file

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Don't use `cut` to parse /etc/passwd.  Much cleaner to do something like: `while IFS=: read name password UID GID GECOS directory shell; do ... done < /etc/passwd`

Comment: Probably prefer `getent` over directly accessing `/etc/passwd` too.

Comment: I agree with all of this, but the teacher wanted us to use certain tools. He admitted there are better ways, and we'll discover them later, but this is what he wants for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think "usrHome" is not set.
What is displayed about L15?

```
echo "Your home directory is $usrHome"
```

Comment: You'll want to use `$HOME` instead anyway. The shell already provides this information.

Comment: I agree with using $HOME as preference, but I'm supposed to get it from /etc/passwd as an exercise in pulling data from a file.

Comment: Forgot to answer your question. usrHome is set on line 7